# Prove following function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Suppose $f:G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is analytic and define $:\phi: G \times G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $\phi(z,w)=\frac{f(z)-f(w)}{z-w}$ if $z \neq w$ and $\phi(z,z) = f'(z)$. Prove that $\phi$ is continuous and for each fixed $w, z \rightarrow \phi(z,w)$ is analytic.

It is intuitively true, can anyone outline a formal proof?

Comment: $\phi$ is a quotient of continuous functions, with non-zero denominator. Try something similar for second case.

Comment: can i prove it from definition of continuous function?

Comment: Haven't you seen that result that the quotient of continuous functions with non-zero denominator is continuous?

Comment: sorry, i have no idea what is "quotient" of continuous functions. it is not a concept from real analysis or complex analysis that i learnt. Anyway thanks for your hint, i found a proof from Rudin's book. T

Comment: You're trying to do complex analysis and you don't know what "quotient" of continuous functions is?! Haven't you studied that if $\;f,g\;$ are continuous then their *quotient* $\;\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}\;$ is continuous *at least* whenever $\;g(x)\neq 0\;$ ?